# How can I change className for specific element when mapping?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to change the index 5 and 6 to opacity 0.2 but I do not know how to change specific className when mapping in react

Here is my following code:

```
  const tabs = [
    "Mission",
    "Agreement",
    "Calendar",
    "Managers",
    "Members",
    "Invitees",
    "Applicants",
    "Sub-Team",
  ];

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

<div className="team-management-tab-items">
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
        <div
          className={
            activeTab === index
              ? "team-management-tab-item selected"
              : "team-management-tab-item"
          }
          key={tab}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={tab}
          onKeyPress={() => {
            return;
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            if (editable === true) {
              setActiveTab(index);
            } else if (index !== 5 && index !== 6) {
              setActiveTab(index);
            }
          }}
        >
          <span className="tab-item-text">{tab}</span>
          <span className="tab-item-indicator" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="team-management-tab-panes">
    {tabs[activeTab] === "Mission" && (
      <Mission
        editable={editable}
        teamId={teamId}
        teamData={teamData}
        fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
      />
    )}
    {tabs[activeTab] === "Agreement" && (
      <Agreement
        teamData={teamData}
        agreement={agreement}
        editable={editable}
        teamId={teamId}
        fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
      />
    )}
   ...
  );
```

Here is how my project look like:

[image]

So basically I want to change opacity Invitees and Applicants to 0.2. How can I do that?

Comment: Something like `index == 5 || index == 6 ?...` in the className?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest would likely be adding an `id` tag to the div like:

```
 {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <div
      id = {tab}
      className={
        activeTab === index
          ? "team-management-tab-item selected"
          : "team-management-tab-item"
      }
```

and then in your css just add

```
#Invitees, #Applicants{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```